Non-Uniform Partition Integrals

What is the specific branch of mathematics that focuses on integrals with non-uniform partitions?
I'm working on solving integrals of this type:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(dx)$$
Alternatively, how is the integral represented with the differential incorporated into the function termed?
Typically, Riemann integrals involve partitions with uniform intervals. However, I've come across problems where this isn't the norm. I'm uncertain about the terminology for these specific types of integrals, which hinders my further investigation into the subject.
Thanks

Do you mean "equal intervals" by "uniform intervals"?

In the Riemann integral $dx$ is just a hint to represent the variable we're integrating with respect to. In fact, in most Analysis texts it is omitted and the notation is $\int_a^b f$.
$f(dx)$ is not a common notation and mostly means nothing.
The integral with interval partitioned into equal subintervals is just a special case of the actual Riemann integral. The definition of this integral is typically given in terms of Darboux sums or Tagged partitions (both are equivalent). You can see this for starting reference.
If you want to learn more about integrals, I suggest that you read some Real Analysis book. Understanding Analysis is good for beginners.
